# array_reduce() for calculating totals

Tags: php

Below is a snippet that uses `array_reduce()` to calculate totals from a detailed dataset.  The data shown is representative of a larger dataset.

This code outputs the expected results.  I'm seeking some peer input on how this `array_reduce()` is written because this is my first time using it in PHP.  I'm more familiar with JavaScript `.reduce()` function.  Is there a more concise way to write this?

```
<?php
$data = [
    'header' => [
        'customerId' => 28449,
        'locationId' => 1278,
        'orderId' => 764,
        'orderDate' => '2022-02-01'
    ],
    'detail' => [
        '0' => [
            'itemId' => 210711,
            'orderQuantity' => 10,
            'fillQuantity' => 8,
            'unitPrice' => 120.54
        ],
        '1' => [
            'itemId' => 582284,
            'orderQuantity' => 151,
            'fillQuantity' => 144,
            'unitPrice' => 85.68
        ],
        '2' => [
            'itemId' => 476537,
            'orderQuantity' => 87,
            'fillQuantity' => 87,
            'unitPrice' => 25.75
        ]
    ]
];

$initialValues = array_fill_keys(['itemCount', 'orderQuantity', 'fillQuantity'], 0);
$totals = [];
$totals = array_reduce($data['detail'], function ($result, $item) {
    $result['itemCount']++;
    $result['orderQuantity'] += $item['orderQuantity'];
    $result['fillQuantity'] += $item['fillQuantity'];
    return $result;
}, $initialValues);


echo '<pre>' . print_r(['data' => $data, 'totals' => $totals], 1) . '</pre>';
?>
```

Here is the `'totals'` output, which is correct:

```
[totals] => Array
    (
         [itemCount] => 3
         [orderQuantity] => 248
         [fillQuantity] => 239
    )
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't see anything to improve inside the callback body.

I do prefer to eliminate single-only variable declarations unless the declaration improves readability or breaks up excessively wide lines of code.

From PHP7.4, concise "arrow function syntax" (`fn() => ...`) is available, but it cannot be used with `array_reduce()` because the syntax does not allow multiline bodies. (Although there is a proposal to accommodate multiline bodies with less syntax -- [PHP RFC: Auto-capturing multi-statement closures](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/auto-capture-closure))

If you are going to write function parameters on multiple lines, then write all parameters on separate lines for easier (human) reading.

Declaring `$total` as an empty array then immediately and unconditionally overwriting it is not needed -- just omit the empty declaration.

Suggested code:

```
$totals = array_reduce(
    $data['detail'],
    function ($result, $item) {
        ++$result['itemCount'];
        $result['orderQuantity'] += $item['orderQuantity'];
        $result['fillQuantity'] += $item['fillQuantity'];
        return $result;
    },
    array_fill_keys(['itemCount', 'orderQuantity', 'fillQuantity'], 0)
);
```

Comment: What is the reason for recommending `++$result['itemCount'];` rather than using `$result['itemCount']++;`?

Comment: Pre-incrementation is a personal preference -- which is why I didn't bullet point that change.  I've read that pre-incrementation is slightly faster than post-incrementation, so by default, I choose this style.  I doubt it makes any difference in any of the scripts that I've written.